# issues with fscanf and seg. faults

Tags: c

```
char temp[100];
char event[1000];
int i = 0;

do {
    while (true) {
        **fscanf(fin, "%s", &temp);**
        if (temp != "BEGIN:VEVENT" || temp != "BEGIN:VCALENDAR") {
            strcat(event, temp);
        }

        if (temp == "END:VEVENT") {
            Events[i][0] = *event;
            i++; 
            break;
        } else if (temp == "END:VCALENDAR") {
            //temp = EOF;
            break;
        }
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", Events[i - 1]);
} while (*temp != EOF);
```

The line I've inclosed in asterisks is causing seg. faults. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what's going on.

Comment: Why are you cmparing temp with a constant char array?  that's not going to do what you think.  You need to use strcmp

Comment: This: "fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", Events[i - 1]);" may blow up if i isn't incremented. or i = 0.

Comment: Mind, the code can never `break` since the only `break` statements lie within unreachable code.

Comment: that's another problem.  too many to list.

Comment: Matt, it is incremented and really only serves as a debug tool - it will not be in the final program.

Edit: I haven't used c in a long long time, I'm still learning string comparisons, etc.

Comment: It's not incremented if the strcmp's don't work.  You should guard against invalid access either way.

Comment: This is also odd. *temp != EOF. You're checking if temp[0] == -1 I think.  Assuming EOF == -1.

Comment: The correct way to check for EOF is to use feof(fin)

Comment: Almost every line of your program has a bug. Fortunately, they have all been mentioned here ... but it's going to take you several iterations, and some study, to get this to work. Also, there's a good chance that it's the strcat, not the fscanf, that segfaults ... you should compile without optimization, and with debug info, and with maximum warnings turned on.

Comment: There are simply too many problems with your code. First of all, compile with warnings, fix them and then we'll talk.

Answer (score 2):

If the line is longer than 100 characters, you may be encountering a buffer overflow. If you just want to get one line of input, use `fgets` instead:

```
if(fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), fin) == NULL) {
    perror("fgets");
    /* return a failure code */
}
```

You also can't compare strings using `==` and `!=`; use `strcmp` instead.

I believe your code crashes because `temp != "BEGIN:VEVENT"` is always true (the address of the `temp` buffer is never equal to the address of a constant string), and so you will continue to `strcat` until the buffer runs out of space, causing the program to buffer overflow `event` and crash.

Comment: Nice try, that'll fix some of it, but far from all of it. The OP's code is UB over UB over UB. I'm not touching it. He should just get a C book and start at chapter 1...

Comment: Yeah, I know. I noticed a few bugs, posted them, and then gave up when I read it a bit more thoroughly...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's that line?  If so, you may have buffer overrun.  Also, you shouldn't pass `&temp` to `fscanf`.  If you use the array without indices, you can imagine it as being a pointer (even though technically it isn't).  So you should do this instead:

```
fscanf(fin, "%s", temp);
```

Also, you do this:

```
strcat(event, temp);
```

But `event` is uninitialised.  You need to at least terminate the `event` string otherwise `strcat` might end up searching through the entire array (depending what uninitialised values are in it) for the end of the string, and potentially overrun:

```
char event[1000];
event[0] = 0;
```

Comment: 'That array is actually a pointer' -- Wrong, and it's seriously frowned upon to say that here at SO. Arrays are converted to pointers to their first element when passed to functions. But: +1 for 'event is uninitialised', as it appears to be declared as an auto.

Comment: Sorry, my bad...  I will adjust my wording. =)